# How do I optimize a firebase query that searches for cards?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my situation:
I sell trading cards online. I store them in numbered "sections" in card boxes, with each section containing roughly 60-75 cards. Having around 150 sections, there is no easy way to find cards that people order without some software. I created a python script that takes in a list of cards that are purchased, accesses my Firebase (Cloud Firestore) database, and returns the different section numbers of each card.

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I want to optimize the Firebase query to minimize the number of sections I need to search through. I have many duplicates of the cards, so I believe optimizing the query like this will save me a significant amount of time searching for cards. I don't really have any idea with how to begin. Can anybody help?

So far, I've created a basic query that gets each card individually and returns the section.

Here is my current query:

```
db = firestore.Client()
collection = db.collection(CARD_COLLECTION_NAME)
docs = collection.where("name", EQUALS, card_name).where(IS_SOLD_PROPERTY, EQUALS, False).get()
for doc in docs:
    db.collection(CARD_COLLECTION_NAME).document(doc.id).set({
        IS_SOLD_PROPERTY: True
    }, merge=True)

return doc._data["inventory_section"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In itself your approach looks fine to me. The only optimization I can think of is to limit it to just retrieving a single card:

```
docs = collection
        .where("name", EQUALS, card_name)
        .where(IS_SOLD_PROPERTY, EQUALS, False).get()
        .limit(1)
```